# Java не запускает файл, который уже скомпилировался

Tags: java

Пишет, что файл был скомпилирован на более поздней версии(58.0) А запустить пытаюсь я на более ранней (54.0). Не знаю, что с этим делать - компилировал файл таким стаком тк(jdk 14.0.2) и J run time (10.0.2) Пробовал устанавливать 7 jdk, файлы переставали компилироваться и пропадала работоспособность javac, ссылку в PATH менял [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно у вас установлены 2 джавы, и одна из них лишняя.
A если вообще (не хочу запутать еще больше), но я для избегания подобных ошибок изпользую `docker`. Он изолирует процесс от основной системы и обеспечивает повторяемость сборки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Версии Java машины

```
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
58 = Java 14
```

Скомпилировав на Java 14 вы не сможете запустить на более ранних версиях.
по таблице видно что установка Java 7 ничем не поможет. Вариант скомпилировать на Java 10 и наедятся что у вас синтаксис Java 10 и зависимости совместимы с Java 10.